# Update tracker.Contact.BehaviorProfiles

Tags: xconnect, tracking

In my Experience Editor i have added the following condition:
where the value of the specific profile key in the contact behavior profile is greater than 3

I update the Contact behavior profile in xConnect from another application and i am then trying to update the Tracker Contact on my Sitecore website. 
Sitecore 9 update 1 has a method to clear the Tracker Contact however i am currently unable to update to 9.1

I have updated the Facet `ContactBehaviorProfile` in the Tracker Contact with succes. However the condition is not triggered. The Tracker Contact also has a property `BehaviorProfiles` I asume this is where the condition checks for the behavior.

My first question would be, am i correct in saying that the condition above looks at the BehaviorProfiles property on the current Contact in the Tracker?

My second question would be, how do i update the BehaviorProfiles property in the tracker Contact from xConnect, the format is different from xConnect and i can't seem to figure it out.

EDIT: I have added 3/5 conditions as a screenshot.
[image]

Comment: Mark, just saw that you created a new question..great...Can you identify the condition that you're using?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 'identify the condition' but the condition i use is in my post above. I've created a profile with 4 different profile keys and check for those

Comment: I meant the Sitecore condition (rules and actions) that evaluates against the facet.